# why I can't do each in params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this inputs

```
<input type="hidden" name="languages[0][name]" value="xx">
<input type="hidden" name="languages[0][level]" value="yy">
```

0 is a value thats change as this inputs are generated dynamically with javascript.

In my controller, I want access to this parameters, and do each, like this:

```
params[:languages].each do |lang|
    @job_offer.job_offer_languages.create name: lang[:name], level: lang[:level]
  end
end
```

`params[:languages]` is :

```
{"0"=><ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Inglés", "level"=>"Bás̄ico"} permitted: false>} permitted: false>
```

So I'm expecting each to give me a hash with name and level,

But in the each `lang` is the key `"0"` as an string, not the parameters.

I've tried with fetch and permit, got the same results.

The only way I made it works is adding this as the first line in the each, but I don't understand why I have to do it.

```
 ...each do |lang|
        lang = params[:languages].fetch(lang)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your `params[:language]` is a hash `each` iterates over its entries and passes `key` and `value` of each entry to a block. Therefore, to access `lang` the way you want you need to the following:

```
params[:languages].each do |index, lang|
    @job_offer.job_offer_languages.create name: lang[:name], level: lang[:level]
  end
end
```

or use ActiveSupport to receive list of lang values to iterate over:

```
 params[:languages].values.each do |lang|
    @job_offer.job_offer_languages.create name: lang[:name], level: lang[:level]
  end
end
```